# jdeveloper 11g create JMS JNDI

Tags: jms, jndi, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

What is the correct way to create JNDI for JMS in jdeveloper 11g so my application can lookup them successfully like this:

```
        public static TopicConnection getTopicConnection( String connectionFactoryName ) throws NamingException, JMSException{

            TopicConnectionFactory  connectionFactory   = null;
            Context                 initCtx             = new InitialContext();

            connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + connectionFactoryName);

            return connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        }
```

One of the JNDI name is jms/Topic.
Additionally when I start my WebLogic server it start looking for JMS jndi's with the string "JNDI"  in the end of the JNDI string.
For an example:
I have jndi jms/Topic
but bea web logic is looking for jms/TopicJNDI.
The jndi's are declared in my web.xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I can't config the jms jndi's is
because I have to declare them in the web.xml and in the weblogic.xml.